# Silverlight and HTML DOM

Tags: html, silverlight

Ok, so this question probably isn't Silverlight specific. 
I have a silverlight 2 page that is stretched, it always fills the browser window. I am overlaying a DIV onto Silverlight, which is working great.

My problem is, the div tag causes empty space below my control, even though the content itself is overlaying the Silverlight control. The end result of this is that there is always a scroll bar in the browser!

How do I get rid of that blank space?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does this happen in all browsers? I've had problems like this in IE (back in the day) because of the funny way it handled new line characters.

Comment: I've only been testing in IE due to intended audience.
In firefox, my div does not appear at all, but I, expectantly, don't get the blank line either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try adding the following to your css

```
div#MySilverLightDiv {    /*change MySilverLightDiv to id of your div */
   overflow: hidden;
}
```